# I See a Lot of `<open></close>` Tag Sets That Contain NO Data, Doesn't This Negate the Tag?

Tags: php, html

As I've been answering questions, I've noticed a lot of code examples that show tags like `<span></span>` with nothing between the tags. What's the point? If there isn't anything between the tags, wouldn't the tag be pointless? 
 I realize that many of them are simply examples, but there also seem to be a number of people  that think it's "okay" to writhe the code that way. Is this a "thing" now?

Comment: If there's no extra attributes such as "id" then I suppose it is rather pointless, especially for inline tags that add no formatting.  However, it could be used as a placeholder for deferred content that could be included by Javascript.  Also depends on the CSS, which could turn the span tag into a block level element, changing the layout slightly.

Comment: It'd be easier to answer your question with *specific* examples, but it's not uncommon to target an empty tag with CSS rules, or for it to be used later on by JavaScript. As an example, the Font-Awesome icon system uses code like `<i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i>` to show an icon.

Comment: @A.J.Parr Thank you! I honestly hadn't thought about it as a placeholder for script, but that does make sense to me. I would probably comment it out, but... for the snippet that is shared, it does make sense. TY! (Care to turn that into an answer?)

Comment: @ceejayoz I think the curiousity came about between `<span>` tags and `<i>` (for the icons) as I recently answered a question concerning them. Not having anything between the opening and closing tag seemed really "odd" to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tags provide the directions or recipes for the visual content that one sees on the Web, they can be stylished by CSS, targeted, modified, injected via Javascript so they can have a utility even if they are empty, it depends on the context.

As you did not provide any particular context, here is an example of text and colored shapes displayed with only empty `<span>` tags:

```css
span{
  display:block;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background-color:yellow;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

span:first-child{
  margin-top:20px;
  background-color:red;
}

span:last-of-type{
  background-color:green;
}

span:first-child::after{
  content: "Dare to say to this cute traffic light that he is pointless ";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
}
span:first-child::before{
  position:absolute;  
  background-color:black;
  height:150px;
  width:50px;
  z-index:-1;
  content:"";
}

span:last-of-type::before{
  position:absolute;  
  background-color:black;
  height:150px;
  width:20px;
  z-index:-1;
  left:22px;
  top:150px;
  content:"";
}
```

```html
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
```

Comment: I would probably code this differently, but I _really_ appreciate the effort! You made a lot of good points. Thank you!